# API-function ChangeDisplaySettings returns DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE (-2)

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

For 5 years I have used this API function to zoom Excel with UserForms. Now it always returns -2 which means the wanted resolution cannot be set.

I found the source code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/technical-content/bb979366(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and I have never changed that code. The problem arises on 2 different PCs, both running Windows 10.

Here is the core code:

```vb
Sub set_Resolution(Width As Long, Height As Long, BpP As Long)

                                        'überprüfen, ob die Grafikkarte den gewünschten Modus unterstützt
    Dim DM          As DEVMODE
    Dim lResult     As Long
                                        ' DEVMODE-Struktur vorbereiten
    With DM
        .dmSize = Len(DM)
        .dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH _
                    Or DM_PELSHEIGHT _
                    Or DM_BITSPERPEL
        .dmPelsWidth = Width                ' Breite
        .dmPelsHeight = Height              ' Höhe
        .dmBitsPerPel = 32                  ' Farben: 2^dmBitsPerPel
    End With
                                        ' Testen, ob die gewünschte Einstellung unterstützt wird:
    lResult = ChangeDisplaySettings(DM, CDS_TEST)
                                        ' Ausgabe des Ergebnisses:
    Select Case lResult
        Case DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL
            MsgBox "Bildschirmmodus kann sofort gesetzt werden.", vbInformation
            lResult = ChangeDisplaySettings(DM, 0)
        Case DISP_CHANGE_RESTART
            MsgBox "Bildschirmmodus kann nach Neustart gesetzt werden.", vbInformation
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Bildschirmmodus kann nicht gesetzt werden.", vbCritical
    End Select
End Sub
```

Because I can't look into the API function, I have no idea what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Because I can't look into the API-function` - yes, [you can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsa). Are you using 64-bit Office? What is your declaration of `DEVMODE` and `ChangeDisplaySettings`, same as in the linked article? Does your display support that mode, can you set it manually?

Comment: Hi SGerg, I know the page - to "look into" means a possibility to track what happens inside. No, I don't use Office 64 (and will never). Declarations are copied from the linked article and never changed. Both displays support the mode, I can set it manually.